# VCR: "There is currently no cassette in use." when creating a second cassette

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, vcr

I'm attempting to do RSpec feature tests on an external API.

My VCR config is as follows:

```rb
VCR.configure do |config|
  config.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr'
  config.hook_into :webmock
  config.ignore_localhost = true
end
```

My test looks like this:

```rb
feature 'Visitor' do

  scenario 'performs an archival', :clean => false, :js => true do 
    mock_login
    visit '/dashboard'
    click_link 'Test Company'
    VCR.use_cassette('feature/archive') do
      within '.nav-app' do 
        click_button 'Quicksave' 
      end
    end
  end

  scenario 'performs a restore', :js => true do
    mock_login
    visit '/dashboard'
    click_link 'Test Company'
    VCR.use_cassette('feature/restore') do
      within '.nav-app' do 
        click_button 'Quickload' 
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The `archive` cassette is created just fine, however the `restore` cassette throws an error:

```
An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:

GET http://SomeApiUrl/...

There is currently no cassette in use.
```

I've obviously told VCR to create and use another cassette with:

```rb
VCR.use_cassette('feature/restore')
```

So what gives?

It's also worth mentioning that I still receive this error even when I clean out my cassette folder and start fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `, :record => :new_episodes` as an argument to `use_cassete`. If you don’t use the record new episodes. It thinks they are the same request.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I've tried that to no avail. Same exact error message occurs regardless.

Comment: @Tristan maybe you are calling an api outside of those VCR wrapping. Try wrapping the whole tests with use_cassette. Also, does the error have a line number?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm dumb. The issue seemed to be that I was using the filename `vcr.rb` to configure VCR; I figured it wouldn't matter being that it was in my `spec/support` folder, but that was not the case.

A simple rename to `vcr_config.rb` fixed the problem right up...